# Sufficient documentation for educational purpose license for USA-Cuba flights?

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, cuba, j1-visas

As a non-US citizen (J-1 visitor status) I am traveling this weekend to Cuba from the USA on a JetBlue flight (Boston-Fort Lauderdale-Havana, Havana-Fort Lauderdale-Boston). As a visitor "located" in the US, I apparently fall under American law, meaning "tourism" is prohibited. I am traveling on an "educational purpose" (OFAC licence, approved through my affidavit), independently, without an agency or an official invitation. Reading through OFAC documentation I interpreted that independent travel is possible if a 24-hour schedule of people-to-people interaction is provided (OFAC doesn't detail on whether, how and where they verify that matter).

I have prepared so far: written list of Cuban houses where I stay and interact with people, places that I visit (museums, schools), local taxi company that lead me to these places, and an oral statement on how this trip relates to my research. I wonder if this is sufficient.

Does anybody have recent experience (since September 2016, and in best case as a US-visitor) regarding what customs border protection officials (both in the USA and in Cuba) require as documentation/statements (if they do) to prove the "educational purpose"?

Your help is much appreciated

Comment: As I understand it, border officials in Cuba are not concerned with US restrictions on US citizens visiting their country.  It may be difficult to predict what interest US border officers might have in your visit to Cuba, since such trips haven't been taking place for a very long time.

Comment: A CBP officer might ask you about your activities in Cuba when you return to the US.

Comment: @ZachLipton OP has to be able to prove that his visit was licenced. I missed the fact earlier that they're flying in on a direct flight

Comment: @MARTA J - how did it go? Given your circumstance it looks like you have experienced the travel firsthand. Care to share with the community?

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, the Cubans don't care about the US's restrictions at all, so you'll have no problems with them.

When it comes to the US, anecdotal evidence suggests that *US citizens* won't face legal repercussions in practice (though they may be asked what they did in Cuba and/or be yelled at)

As a foreigner, however, you are much more vulnerable - you have absolutely no rights at the US border. In essence, if they don't like something you did, they can simply revoke your visa and status on the spot, send you home and ban you from re-entering (or even changing planes there) for many years to come (although as a visa holder, you can appeal through an immigration judge - whether that would be likely to be successful, I do not know).

Of course it will depend on the person you get at the booth, but visas have been revoked in the past for even lesser things, so the possibility, although perhaps not very high, is very real.

From the [Department of State website](https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/country/cuba.html):

> The regulations **require that persons subject to U.S. jurisdiction be licensed** in order to engage in any travel-related transactions pursuant to travel to, from, and within Cuba, or that the transactions in question be exempt from licensing requirements. Transactions related to travel for tourist activities are not licensable. This restriction includes travel to Cuba for tourist activites from or through a third country, such as Mexico or Canada. U.S. law enforcement authorities enforce these regulations at U.S. airports and pre-clearance facilities in third countries. **Travelers who fail to comply with Department of the Treasury regulations may face civil penalties and criminal prosecution upon return to the United States.**

Someone I know is a US green card holder (i.e. permanent resident) and was allegedly (though it's not yet confirmed to me) very close to being deported from the US *for life* after he was caught at the border with a Cuban passport stamp (in February 2016). Fortunately he's rich and could afford an excellent solicitor, whereby the immigration judge (narrowly) decided to suspend his removal proceedings.

"Yet I do not have any official documents (from the USA or Cuba)."

You need to get something from your educational insitution. You are allowed to go to Cuba licenced, **but you need to be able to prove at the US border that your visit was in fact licenced.** It's very strange that **no evidence whatsoever** has been provided by your insitution.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that the US will have a _problem_ with this person traveling to Cuba. Do you have any actual reason to believe this will be the case? If so, can you share it?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Just edited it

Comment: This answer does not seem to reflect the more recent changes in the regulations, under which there are [general licenses](http://blog.jetblue.com/how-easy-to-plan-travel-to-cuba/) to go to Cuba. The question is about how to document that you've complied with the license conditions and whether you'll be asked to show proof of that on return to the US, not whether they'll deport you for life if you don't hide the fact that you've been to Cuba (and hiding such a thing is just going to make you look stupid or like a liar when you're taking a direct flight from Havana on JetBlue).

Comment: The story above looks strange to me. Travel enforcement to Cuba is not enforced by CBP, it is enforced by Treasury Dept. AFAIK violating the licensing regulations is not deportable offence unless he served years of jail time for that. I don't get it.

Comment: @GeorgeY. This is what I was told, haven't read any documentation regarding that case. Possible it was something else in actuality.

Comment: Missed the fact that OP is travelling direct on JetBlue. That negates the option of evading detection by avoiding a Cuban stamp, given APIS

Comment: @Crazydre: maybe then worth marking this as unconfirmed hearsay?

Comment: @GeorgeY. until 2003, the US Customs Service was *a part of* the Treasury department.  Surely, the replacing US Customs and Border Protection agency continues to enforce Treasury regulations as they apply to travelers and goods arriving from overseas.

Comment: @phoog Plus, there are several poorly-defined grounds on which nonimmigrants residing in the US can be stripped of their status. CBP officers then have the ultimate discretion in making an interpretation at the port of entry, although having an immigration judge review the case in court is naturally possible, and they may well be more lenient.

Comment: @Crazydre: however **travel** to Cuba is not prohibited by Treasure Dept, only spending money there. Thus unless some undeclared import was brought in, I don't see on which grounds CBP could even get involved, and how it could end up at immigration judge's desk. Unless they exceeded their authority, but this isn't likely to be the case.

Answer (score 4):

Cuban side has been addressed by both great answers above, which I concur with. Which leaves us with the US side only.

First, travel ban to Cuba (in reality it is ban to spend money in Cuba without license, as the government cannot prohibit travel per se) is only affecting [persons subject to U.S. jurisdiction](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=b5ee59d94ee45bba6a049240298f1cff&mc=true&node=se31.3.515_1560&rgn=div8). **What is jurisdiction?** This means you have to be US citizen (permanent residents also are sometime considered, although this is questionable), or be physically present where US government exercises control. Otherwise you're not under US jurisdiction, and thus the law does not apply to you. Notably having a US visa doesn't by itself subject you to US jurisdiction outside the US, and thus there could be no possible restrictions if you took a connecting flight such as US-Mexico-Cuba.

However in your case you're traveling on a direct flight, and under affidavit. Generally an affidavit alone is enough (if not, you'd be asked to submit supporting documentation when you submit affidavit). Note, however, that the affidavit is submitted not to the airline - who could care less - but to US Government. And submitting a false affidavit to government is a crime. Thus you might be probed (questioning is more likely) by the CBP official on your arrival to the USA to ensure you did not submit a false affidavit.

On the other hand, the legality of the license requirement itself for private citizens to spend money overseas was never challenged in the court, and it is unclear whether our government has an authority to issue such prohibition (effectively trying to make laws for a sovereign country). The  prosecution details I've found so far were related to hiding the fact one's been to Cuba (i.e. lying to CBP officials), or bringing undeclared goods, such as Cuban cigars, which is a different story.

Comment: "The government cannot prohibit travel per se": why not?

Comment: The Travel state Website says "Tourist travel to Cuba is prohibited under U.S. law for U.S. citizens, permanent residents, and **others subject to U.S. jurisdiction.**" As such, not only citizens and perm. residents are subject to US jurisdiction. Do you know anything about this?

Comment: Constitution does not give the government such authority. Only interstate **commerce** could be regulated by acts of Congress.

Comment: @Crazydre: yes, if you're on US soil, aboard of certain vessels or certain places (such as US Embassy/Consulate, or possibly military base), you are under US jurisdiction. As soon as you leave it, well, you're not under US jurisdiction anymore.

Comment: @Crazydre US law is a bit complicated on this point and the State Department  has oversimplified a bit. It's not the _travel per se_ that is banned, but the _spending money_. The US Constitution has been [interpreted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_movement_under_United_States_law) as not allowing the government to restrict the travel of people in most circumstances.

Comment: @GeorgeY. Well, isn't passport control at US airports US soil?

Comment: @GeorgeY. Congress can regulate all sorts of things that have nothing to do with interstate commerce.  The Federal government has sole authority over foreign affairs, for example.

Comment: @MichaelHampton the Wikipedia article states that an attempt to ban travel to Cuba was held to be unconstitutional, but it offers nothing to support that statement.

Comment: @phoog OK, now please read the rest of the article.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I've read the article.  I don't see anything in it aside from that unsupported statement that says that the US government cannot ban its citizens from traveling to Cuba.  In fact, it links to the article on [Zemel v. Rusk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zemel_v._Rusk), which suggests that the government *can* ban travel to Cuba. But otherwise, the freedom of movement article fails to mention the former restrictions that US passports carried making them invalid in certain countries.  It just doesn't seem to be a comprehensive treatment of the subject.

Comment: @phoog: passport is a different issue, but even there the State Department was pushed back by SCOTUS many times (for example, history of dual citizenship in USA). You need to find the authority stating that Gov't *can* do this; Zemel v. Rusk says the Gov't can print on your passport "not valid to travel to Cuba", but Cuba is free to ignore that. Please pay attention how the Gov't tried to weasel this in, instead of simply passing a law prohibiting travel to Cuba w/o Gov't authorization.

Comment: A similar case is Malaysian passport which state "not valid for travel to Israel". However Israel happily accepts those passports as identification, because Malaysia cannot decide which identification Israel should or should not accept (it can accept Malaysian driver license, if it wants to).

Comment: @GeorgeY. of course Cuba is free to ignore that.  Cuba can also choose to admit US citizens without having a passport whatsoever, just as Canada does.  Anyway, the US government "of the people," taken as a whole, can certainly ban its citizens from traveling to Cuba, even if the executive and legislative branches are currently prohibited by the judicial branch from doing so (which isn't clear to me, but whatever), by passing a constitutional amendment allowing the restriction freedom of movement in foreign countries.

Comment: @phoog: the point is that there is no such amendment, so they cannot do that. And passing an amendment is incredibly difficult; the last serious amendment was passed in 1971, and the last one, passed in 1992, was submitted in 1789 (no kidding). And there's a long line of issues for amendments, from gun rights restrictions to gay marriage. So we're safe here.